# Can I write find(), prop(), and css() in one line in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Can I have this in one line ?

```
$(id + 'rptDiv').find('input, button, select, submit').prop("disabled", true);
$(id + 'rptDiv').css({ 'opacity': '0.3', 'filter': 'alpha(opacity = 50)' });
```

This isn't working;

```
  $(id + 'rptDiv').find('input, button, select, submit').prop("disabled", true)
                    .css({ 'opacity': '0.3', 'filter': 'alpha(opacity = 50)' });
```

Comment: what is a <submit> element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `find()` selects child elements that are descendents of the initial query.

You can use `end()` to revert back to the previous query or just do the `css()` part first, before the `find()`.

Answer (score 1):

Set the CSS first before finding the elements.

```
$(id + 'rptDiv')
  .css({ 'opacity': '0.3', 'filter': 'alpha(opacity = 50)' })
  .find('input, button, select, submit')
    .prop("disabled", true);
```